# Spark Job hang when writing out using DF

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

The application exe to `sysDF.write.partitionBy` , and write out first parquet files successfully. But after that, the application hangs with all executors killed, until some overtime occurred. The ACTION code is as below:

```
import sqlContext.implicits._

val systemRDD = basicLogRDD.map(basicLog => if (basicLog.isInstanceOf[SystemLog]) basicLog.asInstanceOf[SystemLog] else null).filter(_ != null)
val sysDF = systemRDD.toDF()
sysDF.write.partitionBy("appId").parquet(outputPath + "/system/date=" + dateY4M2D2)

val customRDD = basicLogRDD.map(basicLog => if (basicLog.isInstanceOf[CustomLog]) basicLog.asInstanceOf[CustomLog] else null).filter(_ != null)
val customDF = customRDD.toDF()
customDF.write.partitionBy("appId").parquet(outputPath + "/custom/date=" + dateY4M2D2)

val illegalRDD = basicLogRDD.map(basicLog => if (basicLog.isInstanceOf[IllegalLog]) basicLog.asInstanceOf[IllegalLog] else null).filter(_ != null)
val illegalDF = illegalRDD.toDF()
illegalDF.write.partitionBy("appId").parquet(outputPath + "/illegal/date=" + dateY4M2D2)
```

Comment: Can you provide some more info, how many rows are in there, and how many distinct values of `appId` are there?

Comment: There are about 100 millions rows and 500 `appId`s

Answer (score 0):

First, the map can be combined with the filter, which should optimise the query a bit:

```
val rdd = basicLogRDD.cache()

rdd.filter(_.isInstanceOf[SystemLog]).write.partitionBy("appId").parquet(outputPath + "/system/date=" + dateY4M2D2)
rdd.filter(_.isInstanceOf[CustomLog]).write.partitionBy("appId").parquet(outputPath + "/custom/date=" + dateY4M2D2)
rdd.filter(_.isInstanceOf[IllegalLog]).write.partitionBy("appId").parquet(outputPath + "/illegal/date=" + dateY4M2D2)
```

First, it is a good idea to cache the `basicLogRDD` as it is used multiple times. The `.cache()` operator will [keep the RDD in memory](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/quick-start.html#caching).
Second, it is not needed to explicitly convert the RDD to a DataFrame, as it is [implicitly converted to a DataFrame](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/sql-programming-guide.html#parquet-files) by implicits, allowing it to be stored using Parquet, (you need to define `import sqlContext.implicits._`).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions!